# SSJS to Publish values in Email from DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I am using below code in email to select all rows from non sendable DE and print them in email.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
try {

//initiate DE using it's External Key  
var myDE = DataExtension.Init("LOG_Error");

//retrieve data without filters  
var data = myDE.Rows.Retrieve();  

Write(Stringify(data));

  } catch (error) {
    Write("<br>error: " + Stringify(error));
}
</script>
```

Using the aboce code I am getting below error when I am doing email preview.

```
error: {"message":"Object expected: Retrieve","jintException":"Jint.Native.JsException: Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MethodCall.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at
```

Any solution?

Comment: Anyone ???......

Comment: Is that the Data Extension Name or the Data Extension External Key being initiated? It needs to be the Data Extension External Key

Comment: It's DE external key

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a good majority of Core functions cannot be used in a messaging context and only in Landing pages and Script Activities.  I will be honest, this is only very lightly documented and is not in anywhere very obvious. For example:

[image]

Now even this is pretty ambiguous on meaning. It could easily be interpreted to just mean that you should use AMPScript first and then only use Core when necessary. So, not exactly definitive...

The closest to an official statement I have found is in Trailhead of all places:

[image]

So in order to do what you want to do, you would either need to use Lookup via the Platform function, AMPScript or use a GET onto a Landing Page/Code Resource that is using this script to gather the results that way. I would not recommend this as that can add a huge process draw on each and every email. If you went this route, I would recommend using **[Script.Util.HttpGet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpGet.htm)** as it caches the value so you would only need to do the call once to get back your info.

For more info on Core, I would recommend looking at my **[series](https://gortonington.com/sfmc-server-side-javascript-4-core-library/)** on it and all things SSJS. I tried to grab all the knowledge and insight around each aspect that I can into a single area. For more on how to handle the response of Script.Util, view this **[blog post](https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/)**. Although it is about HttpRequest() function, the handling of the response section should be identical to HttpGet.